# Failed to create service account "argocd-manager" in namespace "kube-system"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, argocd

I have the following infrastructure:

- Bastion Host
- Private Cluster
- Primary Cluster

I can send kubernetes commands from a bastion host using Tinyproxy to the private cluster. I also installed argocd in the primary cluster and I am trying to link the private cluster in argocd, running the following command:

```
argocd cluster add gke_xxxxx_us-central1_xxxx-private --grpc-web
```

but I get the following error:

```
FATA[0031] Failed to create service account "argocd-manager" in namespace "kube-system": Post "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout
```

I already added the network subrange for the primary cluster to the Control plane authorized networks for the private cluster. This does not seem to work, any ideas? I thought it would be possible for the private and primary clusters to communicate internally or through a nat network.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you can create service account in kube-system namespace using below command

```
kubectl auth can-i create serviceaccount -n kube-system
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a issue with my private cluster, `k auth can-i create serviceaccount -n kube-system 
-- yes`. I should be able to add the networkIP of my primary cluster and add it to the Control plane authorized networks for the private cluster.